# error about dependencies again and again

Tags: symfony

I took my project to another local computer and Im getting this error after requesting `app_dev.php`:

> You must set up the project dependencies by running the following
>   commands:   curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php    php
>   composer.phar install.

So I run those commands but the error is the same again...

Answer (score 0):

You sure you use 2.0 version? Because composer is used in symfony 2.1

Can you show logs which occur when executing `php composer.phar install`?

Else try to:

- Remove extra `php` word in `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install`
- Delete cache and make cache dir writable: `sudo rm -rf app/cache/* && chmod a+rwx -R app/cache/*`